# How to mount a drive in Linux that a non-super user can write to

Tags: mount, rhel

I am attempting to mount an Azure Storage container on a RHEL server that can be written to by a regular user account. I am not the most familiar with Linux, but the command seems simple:

```
mount -t cifs <account name> /mnt/disk -o umask=<umask>,uid=<uid>,username=<Containers master username>,password="<password>",vers=3.0
```

But this is throwing errors, and I'm assuming a syntax error. I have been searching all over, but I haven't seemed to find a good resource for this.

Comment: this looks like a good question to put on severfault.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I read the error and noticed that it was pointing me to a manual page... Found that the gid and umask are not required to specify the uid.